# Loop through a set of HTML files and append text at top and bottom of each file

Tags: shell

For instance, I have an HTML file like this :

```
a.htm

<body>
Hello world!
</body>
```

I want :

```
a.htm

<html>
<LINK href='style.css' rel=stylesheet type='text/css'> 
<body>
Hello world!
</body>
</html>
```

The code I have so far is :

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `ls *.htm`
do
  @echo off
  echo ***New top line*** > temp.txt
  type $i >> temp.txt
  echo ***New bottom line*** >> temp.txt
  mv temp.txt $i
done
```

Errors :

```
abc@bunny:~/fileAppendText$ ./loopAllFilesTest.sh
./loopAllFilesTest.sh: line 5: @echo: command not found
./loopAllFilesTest.sh: line 7: type: i: not found
./loopAllFilesTest.sh: line 9: move: command not found
./loopAllFilesTest.sh: line 5: @echo: command not found
./loopAllFilesTest.sh: line 7: type: i: not found
./loopAllFilesTest.sh: line 9: move: command not found
./loopAllFilesTest.sh: line 5: @echo: command not found
./loopAllFilesTest.sh: line 7: type: i: not found
./loopAllFilesTest.sh: line 9: move: command not found
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You'd like that in `bash` or windows batch script? You seem to mix the style of the two:-).

Comment: don't use `ls` with a `for` loop to list files. Use shell expansion.

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry when I posted this Q. I was not thinking straight, had less than 15 minutes to implement a quick task for our CEO. You guys rock :) 

@ ghostdog : Could you please elaborate on shell expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unix, there is the `cat` command for what you want to do. Create a file "header.txt" and a file "footer.txt". Then do:

```
for i in *.htm; do cat header.txt $i footer.txt > new-$i; done
```

After you checked for correctness, or inside the same for loop if you wish, you can replace the old files:

```
for i in *.htm; do mv new-$i $i; done
```

Comment: Simple awesome! Could you point me to the right source which will make me a a shell script hacker like you?! Thanks again!

Comment: I found that the FLOSS manual at http://en.flossmanuals.net/gnulinux is quite a comprehensive source. while it starts from about zero, all important concepts of the UNIX command line are covered. Also available as PDF: http://en.flossmanuals.net/CommandLineIntro/FM_16Apr09.pdf

Answer (score 1):

```
s="<html>\n<LINK href='style.css' rel=stylesheet type='text/css'>"
for file in *.htm *.html
do
 sed -i.bak "1i $s" "$file"
done
```

or just one line of sed

```
 sed -i.bak "1i $s" *.html *.htm
```

if you are doing it on Windows, you can download the [windows version of sed from GNU](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If by shell-scripting, you mean bash:

- The command is `echo`, not `@echo`. The @ form is specific to Makefiles for not displaying command itself. Moreover `@echo off` doesn't exist in bash and is useless.
- The value of `i` variable is accessed with `$i`.